# Как сделать раскрывающийся блок при наведении на товар?

Tags: magento

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так нужно сделать,но не получается.Я пробую добавить в list.phtml новый блок который будет выводиться при наведении,но похоже это не правильно.Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вносить измененя следует в файл list.phtml в вашей теме. Вот простой пример для базовой темы (`base/default`):

В файле `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` находим *grid view* (обычно в самом низу) и вносим изменения:

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"
            onmouseover="showDescription(this);"
            onmouseout="hideDescription(this);"
            >
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="expandable-description">
                            <div class="expandable-description-inner">
                                <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

**По вышеуказанным изменениям подробнее**:

добавляем обработчик событий на наведение курсора и на противоположное действие:

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"
                onmouseover="showDescription(this);"
                onmouseout="hideDescription(this);"
                >
```

И добавляем наш блок с коротким описанием товара (или еще чемнибудь, чем угодно):

```
<li>
    <div class="expandable-description">
        <div class="expandable-description-inner">
            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Дополнительно к разметке нам понадобятся стили и JS функции, указанные для обработчиков событий. Вот простой пример, он не идеален, но в качестве рабочего примера пойдет, модифицируйте на свое усмотрение:

```
<style>
    .expandable-description {
        display: none;
        height: 0;
        width: 138px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .expandable-description-inner {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 12px 4px;
        z-index: 999;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showDescription(wrapper) {
        wrapper.getElementsByClassName('expandable-description')[0].style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideDescription(wrapper) {
        wrapper.getElementsByClassName('expandable-description')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

Результат работы примера выглядит следующим образом:

[image: результат]

Принцип работы должен быть понятен, если есть фантазия то можно расширить этот функционал.

Надеюсь мой ответ будет полезен.

Comment: @ВикторУлюшев Пожалуйста :)

Comment: Могли бы еще помочь с этим вопросом?http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544775/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-magento

Answer (score 1):

есть блок с position: relative. Второй блок, который будет появляться при наведении спозиционирован абсолютно относительно первого блока и display: none у него будет. а при ховере первого блока ему будет присваиваться display: block

Comment: 2 блок должен находиться на той же позиции что и 1?т.е когда я буду наводить на товар,2 блоку должно присвоиться значение display: block ?

Comment: да, второй блок находиться там же где и первый только он скрыт. и при ховере первого блока-он появляется. а чтобы он был "выше" первого, присвой ему z-index.

Comment: тут еще вопрос в том что у меня этих блоков не 1,а много товаров,как задать чтобы эти блоки создавались для каждого созданого товара?

Comment: На этот вопрос я не смогу тебе ответить( но логика подсказывает что у тебя все блоки одинаковые, т.е. шаблон один и тот же, только картинка, название, цена и описание меняется. А это уже через php, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Спасибо за советы)